# K dimensional WL test

Tags: neural-networks

I am reading a paper on the [K-WL GCN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.02244.pdf). I did not complete the paper yet but I just skimmed over it. There I am trying to understand the K-WL test( page 3 Weisfeiler-Leman Algorithm ). I think my understanding is quite ambiguous, so I looking for an example problem that is solved using K-WL test. But I can't any of them on the web. Does anyone have any solved example problem on K-WL or can anyone explain me how K-WL test works.

Note: If anyone also explain how K-WL GCN uses the K-WL test, I will be thankful.